# writing a query for arangodb that filters data from a graph

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

I have a graph made of two collections, one is a collection of 60,000 services and 10 products, and another is a collection of 1 million edges connecting a product to a service.  We want to find all the service vertices on our graph that are connected to all 10 products.  Basically, we want to find the intersection of all ten products at a single service, and return all the services at which this occurs. Each of the ten products have a distinct product ID.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to write a somewhat efficient query that returns these intersections of products?
Below are some screenshots of a small portion of each of the collections, in JSON format.

[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp6T8.png)

[second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDIP4.png)

Answer (score 1):

The following query use two collections `products` and `edgeCol`. It first collects all of the 10 products in `prods`, then it iterates over all services and for every service it search for all connecting vertices (products) and checks if all of them contains in `prods`.

```
LET prods = (
  FOR product IN products
    FILTER product.ProductType == 'Product'
    RETURN product
)

FOR service IN products
  FILTER service.ProductType == 'Service'
  FILTER prods ALL IN (
    FOR v, e, p IN 1 OUTBOUND service edgeCol
      RETURN v
  )
  RETURN service
```

With only 10 products and over 60,000 services you should think about splitting your collection `products` into two collection `products` and `services` where products only contains your 10 products. You can then drop the field `ProductType`. This allow more performant querying.

```
LET prods = (
  FOR product IN products
    RETURN product
)

FOR service IN services
  FILTER prods ALL IN (
    FOR v, e, p IN 1 OUTBOUND service edgeCol
      RETURN v
  )
  RETURN service
```